# php include not working on IE?

Tags: php, include, internet-explorer

This include is not working in IE:

```
<?php
include_once 'localization.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Global Colleague</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><!--Start Kampyle Exit-Popup Code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Calling an array inside **localization.php**

```
<?php echo l('content_p3'); ?>
```

**EDIT: I tried the same file in another folder and it worked**

Comment: How isn't it working? In particular, what do you expect to happen and what actually happens? What array? What is function `l`? Why are you outputting something before the DOCTYPE?

Comment: And btw: php is executed on the server, not within the browser. It _might_ be that different browsers sent different data and therefore your script acts differently, too. But php itself does not depend on the browser.

Comment: Are you saying that it is working in other browsers?
@VolkerK: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: You should not print stuff before `<html>`.

Comment: Is there an .htaccess related to these folders maybe? Different behaviour between folders could be caused by an .htaccess file set specifically on that folder.

Comment: Sorry guys, I moved all the php files into a new folder and now things are working. (there were a bunch of cgi and htaccess files in the older one).

Comment: That sounds like a caching problem then. If something like that happens again try to append a random query parameter to the url to "convince" the browser to send a new request like e.g. `http://localhost/test.php?foo=972t34rigvif`

Answer (score 1):

"Not working" is very generic. What is it that you expect and what is actually happening? You may want to turn error reporting on and see if any error is reported. In (X)HTML, nothing should be printed before the doctype. Are you trying to add something to the HTTP response? Typically, the browser shouldn't effect how PHP outputs your code unless you've added some code to respond to the user agent which is not always wise.

Perhaps, when you tried your code in another directory it wasn't able to find the offending script as it is included by a relative path. Try removing the include in the original file and see if it "works".

Comment: Haha, sorry I just realized that I didn't specify too much. The php includes were not being included in the index.php file. But now its solved.

Answer (score 0):

The following way 100% work for you:

1) Install (Open Source) Notepad++ On your PC
2) Open the file in it
3) Go to encoding and select (Encode in UTF-8 Without BOM)
4) Then click save
5) Now it can work on (Chrome) and (IE)

:)